# Make a unwind segue from any source to origin of IBAction Unwind

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack-unwinding

I'm performing a unwind action segue from a View Controller so when it's pressed it will go to Call history example:

Call History > Profile Detail > Calling ( this way it works )

Search > Profile Detail > Calling ( This way does execute the cancel action but does not perform the segue)

the name of the Segue is called goToHistory and gets executed using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToHistory" sender: self];
```

and the ViewController is connected to the Exit so I can called the way above.

the way I'm calling the unwind is the following way:

```
- (IBAction)cancelVideoCall:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

}
```

[image]

The ViewController that has the unwind IBACTION is Call History but as you can see when it gets reached from Search > Profile Detail > Calling does not perform the segue to the Call History but it does perform the action then I do Call History > Profile Detail > Calling